# Dyamic query execution

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I want to do the following

```
Statement St =con.createstatement();
Resultset RS=St.executeQuery("select *from table );
while(RS.next()){
     Temp=RS.getInt("number");
}
```

And I want to do run another query within the same while loop

```
Statement St =con.createstatement();
Resultset RS=St.executeQuery("select * from table );
While (RS.next ()){
   Temp=RS.getInt("number");
    RS=St.executeQuery("select * from table2 where number= temp );
}
```

Comment: You are reusing the same `ResultSet`  variable `RS` for second query. Assign it to new variable name

Comment: What issue are you facing?

Comment: Create 2 ResultSets as well as 2 Statement objects.

Comment: Thanx a lot , it worked :)